# I deployed my app on Heroku but then I have cors problems

Tags: node.js, heroku, cors

Since several days now I'm trying to make my app work on Heroku, but I have CORS problem.
I read the package cors documentation and I think I'm doing it right, but you can see my back-end here: https://github.com/Karlus44/orientation-back
(I'll paste the relevant code)
You can also find my front-end here: https://github.com/Karlus44/orientation-front
and see that when you go to my app (here: https://orientation-front.herokuapp.com/ ) you have some CORS errors.
Thanks for any help
Here is the code in my server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');

//many declarations


const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://orientation-front.herokuapp.com',
  methods: 'GET,POST',
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}


app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));



app.get('/',cors(corsOptions), (req,res)=>{
  return db('utilisateurs').count('id')
  .then(data => res.json(data));
})

//example of request

app.post('/signin', cors(corsOptions), (req,res) => {signin.handleSignin(req,res, db, bcrypt)})
```

Comment: Have you added your cors packages in "devDependencies", Please add it in "dependencies"?

Comment: well, it was already in my dependencies. now i've added it in my devDependencies as well, but nothing changed

Comment: You should use app.use(cors()); instead of app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));.

Comment: I tried your modification, but still get the same probleç

Comment: You should use app.use(cors()); at line number five in your sever.js file.

Comment: i tried, but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for trying.
The error was in fact in my requests in my front files. The link was wrong.
I just needed to change all my 'https://git.heroku.com/orientation-back.git/'
into 'https://orientation-back.herokuapp.com/'